# Trying to start MySQL from MacOS

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I am all new to Iava and JDBC. Probably making a simple mistake. I am trying to start MySQL from NetBeans with the following server properties:

[image]

I get the following error messages:

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/mysql-8.0.0-dmr-osx10.11-x86_64/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2020-08-13T10:45:33.948213Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-08-13T10:45:33.948830Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2020-08-13T10:45:33.948973Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.0-dmr-osx10.11-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.0-dmr) starting as process 29862 ...
2020-08-13T10:45:33.963298Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-8.0.0-dmr-osx10.11-x86_64/data/Mauritss-MacBook-Air.lower-test
2020-08-13T10:45:33.963374Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-8.0.0-dmr-osx10.11-x86_64/data/Mauritss-MacBook-Air.lower-test
2020-08-13T10:45:33.963913Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to /usr/local/mysql-8.0.0-dmr-osx10.11-x86_64/data/
2020-08-13T10:45:33.963935Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-08-13T10:45:33.964020Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-08-13T10:45:33.964169Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.0-dmr-osx10.11-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I realise I probably have to add some connector but I don't know where and how.

Comment: How are you starting mysql? "Permission denied" suggests you are either using the wrong user, or that the permissions on that directory are incorrect

Comment: Your problem is not related to JDBC, so I have removed that tag. Your problem is with starting MySQL.

Comment: Following changes made: --skip-grant-tables & changed time_zone in mysql server. 

Now it works. Have no thorough idea why ...

Thanks for contributing!